# unresolved reference text in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, reference

I am getting an error for using .text, error reads "Unresolved reference:text"
I have tried removing "apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'" from build.gradle syncing, adding it back, and then re-syncing.

```
    package com.example.myapplication

    import android.content.pm.PackageManager
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.WorkSource
    import android.view.*
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode
    import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector

    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import java.util.jar.Manifest
     class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var svBarcode: SurfaceView
        private lateinit var tvBarcode: TextureView

        private lateinit var detector: BarcodeDetector
        private lateinit var cameraSource: CameraSource

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

            svBarcode = findViewById(R.id.sv_barcode)
            tvBarcode = findViewById(R.id.tv_barcode)

            detector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS).build()
            detector.setProcessor(object : Detector.Processor<Barcode>{
                override fun release() {}
                override fun receiveDetections(detections: Detector.Detections<Barcode>?) {
                    val barcodes = detections?.detectedItems
                    if(barcodes!!.size() > 0){
                        tvBarcode.post{
                            tvBarcode.text = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue
                        }
                    }
                }

            })


            cameraSource = CameraSource.Builder(this, detector).setRequestedPreviewSize(1024, 768)
                .setRequestedFps(25f).setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build()

            svBarcode.holder.addCallback(object : SurfaceHolder.Callback2 {
                override fun surfaceRedrawNeeded(holder: SurfaceHolder?) {}
                override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder?, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {}
                override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder?) {
                    cameraSource.stop()
                }
                override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder?) {
                    cameraSource.start(holder)
                }

            })

            fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
            return true
        }

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            return when(item.itemId) {
                R.id.action_settings -> true
                else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
        }
    }
```

I am really new to Kotlin and Android dev, hoping that there is a simple solution that I am overlooking. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Its kotlin file then you have to YOUR_FILE_NAME.kt extension

Comment: `tvBarcode.text` - .text does not exist. What do you want to do here?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the issue in much clear way.

Comment: @sanjeev I am trying to make a barcode scanner, recieveDetections gets the scanned barcode and tv.Barcode.text is meant to check whether there are text elements there and then display them

Comment: Please Check your line :  private lateinit var tvBarcode: TextureView, correct is  private lateinit var tvBarcode: TextView

Comment: @RahulKhatri THANK YOU!!!